Is it possible to throttle a single URL in IIS
Our production IIS web server keeps coming to a halt because a web application is occasionally hitting a single URL faster than the server can respond.
Is it possible in IIS to throttle/limit that single URL so the rest of the site will carry on as normal during these spikes? Is so how?
I am in the process of fixing the application but that will take time and this config fix will help until a permanent fix is in place.

As far as I know, only Request Limits limit http requests in iis, but this does not seem to meet your needs, so I think it is impossible to do in iis.
